# React state update error whenever i open someone's image, and image not redering too. How can I fix this error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, use-effect

I was creating a snapchat like web app and this is the chats page where all different snaps were commoing from different users, but when I open their snap their image is not rendering and I'm always ending with this error -

Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
at Chats

````
import "./Chats.css";
import { Avatar } from "@material-ui/core";
import SearchIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Search";
import ChatBubbleIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChatBubble";
import { auth, db } from "./firebase";
import Chat from "./Chat";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectUser } from "./features/appSlice";
import RadioButtonUncheckedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/RadioButtonUnchecked";
import { useHistory } from "react-router";
import { resetCameraImage } from "./features/cameraSlice";

const Chats = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const user = useSelector(selectUser);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("posts")
      .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
        setPosts(
          snapshot?.docs.map((doc) => ({
            id: doc.id,
            data: doc.data(),
          }))
        )
      );
  }, []);

  const takeSnap = () => {
    dispatch(resetCameraImage());
    history.pushState("/");
  };

  return (
    <div className="chats">
      <div className="chats__header">
        <Avatar
          className="chats__avatar"
          src={user.propilePic}
          onClick={() => auth.signOut()}
        />
        <div className="chats__search">
          <SearchIcon className="chats__searchIcon" />
          <input placeholder="Friends" type="text" />
        </div>
        <ChatBubbleIcon className="chats__chatIcon" />
      </div>
      <div className="chats__posts">
        {posts.map(
          ({
            id,
            data: { profilePic, username, timestamp, imageUrl, read },
          }) => (
            <Chat
              key={id}
              id={id}
              profilePic={profilePic}
              username={username}
              timestamp={timestamp}
              imageUrl={imageUrl}
              read={read}
            />
          )
        )}
      </div>
      <RadioButtonUncheckedIcon
        className="chats_takePicIcon"
        onClick={takeSnap}
        fontSize="large"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chats;```
````

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the fact that `onSnapshot` function subscribes the component to real-time Firebase updates, even if the component is unmounted, so you have to return a unsubscription function on your useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = db.collection("posts")
    .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
    .onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
      setPosts(
        snapshot?.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data(),
        }))
      )
    );

  return () => unsubscribe();
}, []);
```